# Adding File Text With Sed

Tags: sed

```
#!/bin/bash
search_string="\/sbin\/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12443 -j ACCEPT";
delimeters=$(cat /root/firewall/firewall.txt);
sed -i "s/$search_string/$delimeters$search_string/" /root/result.txt
```

I want to add the contents of the `/root/firewall/firewall.txt` into `/root/result.txt` file before a line which is saved in `search_string` variable.

If `/root/firewall/firewall.txt` contains one line above script works. But if the firewall.txt contains multiple lines, script breaks as:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 64: unterminated `s' command
```

I think, new line characters causing the problem but I could not properly backslash it.

```
search_string="\/sbin\/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12443 -j ACCEPT";
delimeters=$(cat /root/firewall/firewall.txt);
replaced= "$delimeters" | sed -r 's/\\n/\\\\n/g'
sed -i "s/$search_string/$replaced$search_string/" /root/result.txt
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: what is the output you expect?

Comment: It should add the multiple line contents of `firewall.txt` into `result.txt` before `/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12443 -j ACCEPT` line.

Comment: and the linebreaks should be still there the same way as in the firewall.txt?

Comment: yes, I just backslashed because the first script did not work.

Comment: you sure this is about linebreaks? maybe some other character in the firewall.txt could cause this?

Comment: double checked. I used simple words. If the contains 1 sentence, the script works but 2 sentences break it.

Comment: ok, last shot for the simple things... :) how about changing third line like this?
`replaced=\`echo $delimeters" | sed -r 's/\\n/\\\\n/g'\``

Comment: It is evaluating the `firewall.txt` as command and throws `command not found`

Comment: it is really in the newlines. being line-based sed does not understand them well. this should help you understand how to insert newlines (you will probably end up reworking your script)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723157/how-to-insert-a-newline-in-front-of-a-pattern

Comment: @Fiisch Thank you very much for your help. I tried the codes on that page but could not manage in. Do you mind the posting the solution, if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This overlaps somewhat with some of the other answers.)

1. I’m somewhat confused.  You say,

   > I want to add the contents of the `firewall.txt` file
   >   into the `result.txt` file
   >   ***before*** a line which is saved in `search_string` variable.

   OK, first of all, if they aren’t an essential part of the question,
   full pathnames (`/root/…`) clutter your question and add no value. 
   Just use simple filenames.  After all,
   I hope you’re debugging this in a local directory, ***not*** running as root.

   Secondly, what ***is*** useful is giving some example data. 
   Not the 2000 lines that you actually have in your actual files,
   but a handful of lines. 
   (Again: you are debugging this on test files, aren’t you?) 
   For example, say `result.txt` contains

   ```
   One, two,
   /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12443 -j ACCEPT
   Buckle my shoe.
   ```

   and `firewall.txt` contains

   ```
   Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall.
   ```

   You say,

   > If `firewall.txt` contains [only] one line, the script
   >
   > ```
   > #!/bin/bash
   > search_string="\/sbin\/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12443 -j ACCEPT";
   > delimeters=$(cat /root/firewall/firewall.txt);
   > sed -i "s/$search_string/$delimeters$search_string/" /root/result.txt
   > ```
   >
   > works.

   (By the way, you don’t need the semicolons at the ends of the lines,
   and the word “delimiter” is spelled with the word “limit” in the middle.) 
   Well, the above produces this result:

   ```
   One, two,
   Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall./sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12443 -j ACCEPT
   Buckle my shoe.
   ```

   Is *that* really what you want? 
   Because that’s not what most people think when you say,
   “add [text] into [a] file ***before*** a line”,
   especially when you start talking about the text to be inserted
   being more than one line,
   and especially since you said the linebreaks should be still there
   the same way as in the `firewall.txt`. 
   I’ll assume that you really want

   ```
   One, two,
   Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall.
   /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12443 -j ACCEPT
   Buckle my shoe.
   ```

   If you want the last line of the `firewall.txt` file
   concatenated with the `/sbin/iptables` line,
   please explain more precisely what you want.
2. You say,

   ```
   search_string="\/sbin\/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12443 -j ACCEPT";
   delimeters=$(cat /root/firewall/firewall.txt);
   replaced= "$delimeters" | sed -r 's/\\n/\\\\n/g'
   sed -i "s/$search_string/$replaced$search_string/" /root/result.txt
   ```

   Well, that’s nonsense; the third line responds

   ```
   -bash: Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall.: command not found
   ```

   Perhaps you meant

   ```
   replaced=$(echo "$delimeters" | sed -r 's/\\n/\\\\n/g')
   ```

   ?
3. OK, even if you had said

   ```
   replaced=$(echo "$delimeters" | sed -r 's/\\n/\\\\n/g')
   ```

   it wouldn’t have done any good, because `sed` normally works
   a line at a time, and it isn’t going to see newlines as characters in lines
   (even if its input is coming from a shell variable
   that has a multi-line value;
   that’s no different from a file with multiple lines). 
   What does work (eliminating a [useless use of `cat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat)) is

   ```
   replaced=$(sed 's/$/\\/' firewall.txt)
   sed "s/$search_string/$replaced
   $search_string/" result.txt
   ```

   using `sed 's/$/\\/'` to add a backslash
   at the end of every line in `firewall.txt`. 
   You need to type a newline (<kbd>Enter</kbd>) after `$replaced`
   because the last newline gets stripped off
   when you do the `replaced=$(…)` command substitution. 
   And, just for simplicity’s sake,
   if you want to leave the `/sbin/iptables` command untouched,
   you might want to consider changing the final command to

   ```
   sed "s/$search_string/$replaced
   &/" result.txt
   ```

   using `&` in the replacement string to say
   “insert here the text that was found by the search string (regex)”.
4. While the `s` command will allow you to insert entire lines,
   it wasn’t really meant for that.  There are `a`, `i`, and `c` commands
   for inserting one or more entire lines from the command string. 
   But, since your insertion text is coming from a file,
   it makes the most sense to look at the `r` (**r**ead) command. 
   As a first cut,

   ```
   sed "/$search_string/r firewall.txt" result.txt
   ```

   will do almost what you want.  Almost. 
   Unfortunately, it will inject the contents of the `firewall.txt` file
   after the `/sbin/iptables` line. 
   I was able to find a workaround
   (to get the contents of `firewall.txt` before the `/sbin/iptables` line),
   but it’s grievously complicated:

   ```
   sed -n -e "/$search_string/{s/^/+/; h; r firewall.txt
   n}" -e 'x; s/^+//p; s/.*//; x; p' result.txt
   ```

   Apparently `sed` won’t recognize `;` as a delimiter to end a filename,
   so, when we say `r firewall.txt`, we must type <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   Here we go:

   - `-n`: Don’t write output except as commanded by `p` or `r` commands.
   - `/$search_string/{…}`: For each line matching `$search_string`
     (`/sbin/iptables …`), do the following:

     - `s/^/+/`: Insert a `+` at the beginning of the line
       (creating `+/sbin/iptables …`). 
       This flags the line as being a match for the search string. 
       (I’ll get back to that.)
     - `h`: Copy the pattern space (`+/sbin/iptables …`) to the hold space.
     - `r firewall.txt`: Read the `firewall.txt` file
       (and write its contents).
     - `n`: Stop processing this line and read the next one.
   - Then, for every *other* line (those *not* matching `$search_string`),
     do the following:

     - `x`: Exchange the contents of the hold and pattern spaces. 
       I.e., the line we just read (the one *not* matching `$search_string`)
       goes into the hold space,
       and we copy into the pattern space the previously held line
       (which might be `+/sbin/iptables …` and might be blank).
     - `s/^+//p`: If the line is a saved match of the search string
       (i.e., it is a *flagged* line containing `+/sbin/iptables …`),
       strip off the `+` and print the rest. 
       Otherwise, print nothing.
     - `s/.*//`: Wipe out the line (replace everything with nothing). 
       I would have liked to do `d` (**d**elete) here,
       but that terminates processing of the current line.
     - `x`: Exchange the contents of the hold and pattern spaces again. 
       Move the blank line from the pattern space into the hold space,
       and retrieve the line from `result.txt` that we just stashed there. 
       And finally …
     - `p`: Print the line from `result.txt`.

   In short,

   - When we find a line matching `$search_string` (i.e., `/sbin/iptables …`),
     we save it in the hold space (without printing it),
     and read (and print) the `firewall.txt` file.
   - For every other (i.e., non-matching) line,
     we pull the saved line (if any) out of the hold space and print it,
     and then print the current line.

   Argh!  This fails if `/sbin/iptables …` occurs on the last line,
   because it gets saved in the hold space,
   but there’s no subsequent non-matching line to trigger its extraction.

   So let’s just make sure that `/sbin/iptables …`
   never occurs on the last line,
   by adding a dummy line at the end, and then strategically removing it.

   ```
   echo >> result.txt
   sed -n -e "/$search_string/{s/^/+/; h; r firewall.txt
   n}" -e 'x; s/^+//p; $d; s/.*//; x; p' result.txt
   ```

   The `$d` causes the last line to be deleted. 
   (We could use `$q` and get the same effect.)

   This does work if there are multiple `iptables` lines. 
   But, yes, it is getting to be something of a kludge. 
   I guess the
   `sed "s/$search_string/$replacednewline&/"`
   answer isn’t looking so bad now.

Comment: Thank you very much @G-Man for your detailed answer. Yes, code had some flaws. I just could not figured out why new lines were eaten by sed. I could fix the new line issue by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1618234). Your 3rd method also doing the job. It is good to learn sed is designed to work with line by line.

Comment: Thanks for having the patience to read a long, late answer.  I'm glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

While this is likely possible with some `sed` calisthenics, I would use another tool instead. Perl, for example:

```
search_string="\/sbin\/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12443 -j ACCEPT";
delimeters=$(cat /root/firewall/firewall.txt);
perl -i -pe "s/$search_string/$delimeters$search_string/" /root/result.txt
```

Comment: your method works @terdon. But I would like to handle by sed if possible.

Answer (score 0):

sed has more commands than just `s///` -- there's an `r` command to read another file into the current stream. However that reads the file *after* the current line, and you want to place it *before* the current line, so we have to juggle a bit. Note that you do not have to escape the slashes in the search string, we can use alternate delimiters in sed.

```
$ cat result.txt
foo
bar
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12443 -j ACCEPT
baz

$ cat firewall.txt
firewall line 1
firewall line 2

$ search_string="/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12443 -j ACCEPT"

$ sed "\%${search_string}% {
                     # we have hit the search string:
    x                # move the current line to hold space
    r firewall.txt   # queue the file for reading
    N                # append the next line from results
                     # -> this triggers the actual file read and printing
    s/\n//           # the "x" command left behind a blank line so we remove it
    H                # append the current line to the hold space   
    g                # then bring the hold space to the pattern space
}" result.txt
```

```
foo
bar
firewall line 1
firewall line 2
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12443 -j ACCEPT
baz
```

---

The sed command can be shrunk to

```
sed "\#${search_string}#{x;r firewall.txt
N;s/\n//;H;g}" result.txt
```

GNU sed seems to require a newline after the filename.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if several lines match `${search_string}`. Also, the real problem is when the last line matches (as you can't pull the `N`ext line)... Definitely not a job for `sed`, unless you have _gnu sed_: `sed "\|${search_string}|e cat firewall.txt" result.txt` should work irrespective of the number of lines matching pattern and their position...

Comment: Glenn-jackman it did not work. I am using CentOS terminal, though. Thanks anyway. @don-crissti your method works. Thank you very much for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/\-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0\/24 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT/a CLIENTSCRIPT2="hello.sh"' file.txt
```

In this case i added the variable CLIENTSCRIPT2="hello.sh"' on  file.txt
just under -A INPUT...etc
Note the backslash escape in the syntax